# Hover over div, that particular div expands while the other two divs shrinks

Tags: html, css

I have created a website and I want to animate the particular section by expanding the div as well as shrinking the divs beside it, like how the design of the website of http://minimalmonkey.com/ is. I have to write a code:

```
<style>
.col-sm-4 {
    -webkit-transition: width 0.2s;
    transition: width 0.2s;
}

.col-sm-4:hover {
    background-color : orange ;
    width : 600px ;
    <!--height : 10000 px ; -->
    font-weight : weight ;
}
</style>

<div class="col-sm-4">
  ...
</div>

<div class="col-sm-4">
  ...
</div>
```

where .col-sm-4 is my div, but it does not affect the other divs beside it. Does anyone have any idea on how to approach this?

Any comments will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: How about doing display: relative in the hover?

Answer (score -1):

You could just invert the padding and margin on hover.

It would give the illusion of the container getting bigger and not effecting the others beside it. Good luck.

```css
.col-sm-4 {
  width: 100px;
  -webkit-transition: width 0.2s;
  transition: width 0.2s;
  float: left;
  background: pink;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 5px;
}

.col-sm-4:hover {
  background-color: orange;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 5px;
  font-weight: 700;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-sm-4">
  ...
</div>

<div class="col-sm-4">
  ...
</div>

<div class="col-sm-4">
  ...
</div>

<div class="col-sm-4">
  ...
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You could keep the column widths as they are but give them `overflow: visible` then have a child element which expands on hover

The snippet shows a simple way you could do this

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.col-sm-3 {
  position:relative;
  overflow:visible;
  text-align:center;
  
  /* These are just to show as example without loading bootstrap */
  padding: 0 15px;
  width: 80px;
  -webkit-transition: width 0.2s;
  transition: width 0.2s;
  height:120px;
  display:inline-block;
}

.expandMe {
  background: cornflowerblue;
  top:0;
  right: 0;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  padding:15px;
  position:absolute;
  border:2px solid #333;
}

.expandMe:hover{
  background:green;
  width: 130%;
  left:-15%;
  right:-15%;
  z-index:1;
}

.col-sm-3:first-child > .expandMe:hover {
  width: 115%;
  right: -15%;
  left: 0;
}

.col-sm-3:last-child > .expandMe:hover {
  width: 115%;
  left: -15%;
  right: 0;
}

.p-0,
.col-sm-3.p-0{
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="col-sm-3 p-0">
    <div class="expandMe">Content</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-3 p-0">
    <div class="expandMe">Content</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-3 p-0">
    <div class="expandMe">Content</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-3 p-0">
    <div class="expandMe">Content</div>
  </div>
</div>
```